# Laravel - Alternative root domain on verification email link

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-fortify

I have a Laravel application which can be accessed from multiple clients all of which have their own domain (eg myclient.com). In addition, there is a core client (for the sake of this example using the domain coreclient.org).

Users associated to the core client are able to sign up users for any of the other clients.

Admin users for any other client are able to sign up users only for their client.

This uses the base code from Fortify.

It's all fine until it comes to the account verification email when a new user is created by the core client for a different client. The link in the verification email uses the core client domain rather than client the new user belongs to.

eg `http://coreclient.org/email/verify/1/dd8...8ad?expires=1639608547&signature=718...1ee`

It needs to be `http://myclient.com/email/verify/1/dd8...8ad?expires=1639608547&signature=718...1ee`

To fix this, I replaced the domain in the url string after it is generated but this causes an invalid signature as I'm assuming this is generated based on the domain of the person creating the new user.

Here's what I have so far in the boot function of my AuthServiceProvider file... any ideas?

```
VerifyEmail::createUrlUsing(function ($notifiable) {

    $verifyUrl = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
        'verification.verify',
        Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
        [
            'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
            'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
        ]
    );

    // This amends the domain in the URL if core client user creating for another client - creates mismatch with signature though
    if(auth()->user()->client->is_core && auth()->user()->client_id != $notifiable->client_id) {
        $verifyUrl = Str::replace(auth()->user()->client->domains->first()->domain, $notifiable->client->domains->first()->domain, $verifyUrl);
    }

    return $verifyUrl;
});
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this btw?

Comment: @sij_a The "solution" was to enable Core Client users to login to the other client's platforms and add the new users from there. So I didn't really solve the problem as such, but came up with an alternate approach to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The signature depends on your `APP_KEY`.
To publish it to other application should not discussed. It is a no go.

You can customize with key which it should resolved with.

Paste this code in here:

`App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function register()
{
  $this->app->make('url')->setKeyResolver(function () {
    return $this->app->make('config')->get('app.shared-signed-key');
  });
}
```

This code needs to be on the `coreclient` and on the `myclient` so they can both generate and resolve it.

You can get a deep view with following methods:

- `\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::signedRoute`
- `\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::setKeyResolver`
- `\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider::registerUrlGenerator`

Comment: In my case, these are not 2 separate applications. It's a single application that can be accessed from multiple domains - therefore they share the same APP_KEY.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem:
I needed to send the link with a subdomain; Check my own answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71973086/1825418

you'll have to adapt the code because i use "tenan_route" which is a function from the tenancy_laravel, which automatically add the subdomain route, in your case you just nee to change that function to some other with the full domain domain you want to use in both positions where i use "tenant_route" (one for the link itsel, the other to be used by laravel to generate the correct signature)

It works like a charm!

Good Luck